# Flatten 'reactive' call results in Scala

Tags: scala, future, reactive-programming

By repeatedly chaining asynchronous calls, I end up with this awful type:

```
Seq[Future[Option[Future[T]]]]
```

Is there a way to simplify it to a more manageable:

```
Future[Seq[T]]
```

As in:

```
def simplify[T](x: Seq[Future[Option[Future[T]]]]): Future[Seq[T]] = ???
```

Avoiding the use of `Await`?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
def simplify[T](arg: Seq[Future[Option[Future[T]]]]):Future[Seq[T]] = {
  val seq: Future[Seq[Option[Future[T]]]] = Future.sequence(arg)
  val ret1 = seq.map { seq => Future.sequence(seq.flatten)}
  ret1.flatMap(identity)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I came up with a more concise (though rather cryptic): Future.sequence(x).map(\_.flatten).flatMap(Future.sequence(\_))